# TP4056-42 Without battery temperature sensor

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging

I would like to create an integrated circuit with the IC TP4056-42 but without the battery temperature sensor. The datasheet speaks that when we do not use temperature sensor we must ground the pin 1 TEMP. In some circuits on the internet the TEMP pin has a resistor connected to the VCC. But the datasheet does not say anything about it, I wonder if the circuit below is correct.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you follow what the datasheet recommends? Can you post the other circuits that show a resistor to VCC?

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet:

> ***Temperature Sense Input:***  ... If TEMP pin’s voltage is below 45% or above 80% of supply voltage VIN for more than 0.15S, this means that
>   battery’s temperature is too high or too low, charging is suspended.
>   The temperature sense function can be disabled by grounding the TEMP
>   pin.

If you do not want to use it, ground it.

Perhaps the online schematics that you mention are faking a signal to be within the 45% to 80% range?  It's hard to say without examples.